Why does shell-mode truncate ps output?
Startup a fresh GTK emacs with no config with emacs -Q. Then run M-x shell. Then at the prompt:
$ ps -ef
Long commands will be truncated to the frame width, like this:
root      526315       2  0 15:08 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/6:2-eve

So far, this matches normal terminal behavior. But if you do:
$ ps -ef | grep kworker
In emacs shell-mode it will still be truncated, but in a non-emacs terminal (e.g. xterm) the line will not be truncated. Why is this? How do I get it to match normal terminal behavior?
I've noticed shell-mode will respect $COLUMNS, so you can set it to a large value as a temporary fix, but this is unnecessary in a regular terminal where piping will prevent truncation regardless of the $COLUMNS value, and shell-mode always assigns $COLUMNS back to the frame width on the next command.

In bash, export -p | grep COLUMNS shows me that this variable is exported in my *shell* buffer, but not in my regular terminal.
export -n COLUMNS in my *shell* buffer therefore has the effect you're after.
Original answer follows...

The man page for my version of ps says:

If ps can not determine display width, as when output is redirected
(piped) into a file or another command, the output width is
undefined (it may be 80, unlimited, determined by the TERM variable,
and so on).  The COLUMNS environment variable or --cols option may
be used to exactly determine the width in this case.  The w or -w
option may be also be used to adjust width.

Where the latter options are:

w      Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.
-w     Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.

And indeed for me, ps -wwef | grep <whatever> has the desired effect in a shell buffer.
My ps also support any of the following set a specific screen width:

--cols <N>
--columns <N>
--width <N>


this is a good workaround, but doesn't explain why the emacs behavior is different. when I invoke ps ... | grep .. bash is still responsible for doing the piping between ps and grep, so I wouldn't expect ps to behave differently

They'll be making decisions based on the environment they observe, and something in those differences will be driving that decision.  I don't know what, specifically.  As the chosen width is explicitly "undefined" in that situation, though, neither of the two outcome is incorrect.

In my case at least, I suspect the decision is driven by the fact that in the two different scenarios I get a different result from the following: echo $COLUMNS | sh -c 'cat - && echo and && echo $COLUMNS'

export -n COLUMNS in my *shell* buffer has the effect you're after.  export -p | grep COLUMNS shows that it is exported in my *shell* buffer, but not in my regular terminal.

I observe that if you change COLUMNS in the shell buffer, then hit enter a couple of times, the old value magically comes back

Yes, I believe Emacs tries to keep it synchronised with the current window width.
